# How can I pass @Model to Angular ng-init

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

Isn't it possible to pass @Model to `ng-init` in ASP.NET MVC 4 view? When I do it like `data-ng-init=init(@Model)` it is undefined in the `init()` function.

```
$scope.init = fuynction(model){
    console.log(model); // prints undefined
}
```

By the way I'm new to AngularJs. Any help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: Remember, Angular is running on the browser and only knows about client-side JavaScript.  To use the model, you would need to serialize `@Model` into something that JavaScript can understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Serialize you model into json string, using Newtonsoft.Json assembly or similar and pass the serialization result to data-ng-init.

Answer (score 17):

As I commented, you need to translate between your server-side objects (e.g. `@Model`) and client-side objects.

For example, if you just wanted to use the `Name` property of `@Model` you could do something like this:

```
<div ng-init="init('@Model.Name')"></div>

$scope.init = function(name){
    console.log(name); // prints value of name
}
```

Notice, that even in this simple example, it is necessary to format `@Model.Name` into a JavaScript string (by putting quotes around it).

Probably, you don't want to use the *entire* `@Model` object.  It is best to choose only the fields you want and pass them in individually.

If you need access to a lot of data from the server, it is recommended to use `$http` service and make a server call for the data.

Comment: Even When I pass @Model.Name it is still null. I Used this: `data-ng-init="init(@JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model))`. It worked.

Comment: Do you need anything additional to use @JsonConvert?

Answer (score 3):

inlcude the @using ProjectApp.Models then data-ng-    init="init(@Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model))"