# Accessing ng-init inside $scope from razor file Model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am having trouble finding a way to get the index off of a property on a razor file.  I need to match the index of the table to the array that I have on scope.

I set a window value from my cshtml file to a scope property.

```
scope.discountFlightList = dealViewModel;
```

**dealViewModel** contains an array of items. Most importantly deal.Fare

I need to access a certain index of the array each time the button located on the razor file is clicked.  Below is the button that I am working with.

```
 <a href="" ng-click="openPriceChart()" class="btn-primary btn-sm pull-right hide-on-mobile"><span ng-bind-html="@deal.Fare | roundPrice | superCurrency: '@Language.Currency' : true"></span>* <i class="ha-icon fontIcon-angle-right"></i></a>
```

The index that I need is based on the fare value that I can see on ng-init which exists on each  **td**  of

```
<td ng-init="myInit('@deal.OriginText')"> // in dev tools = San Francisco, California
```

Ideally I would know what the index is when I click on the  **a href**  and set it to the array index.  I was hoping this answer would do it
[How can I pass @Model to Angular ng-init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22039198/how-can-i-pass-model-to-angular-ng-init)

```
var testValue
$scope.myInit = function(name){
testValue = name;
```

}

But I am getting an empty string when I check on my debugger.

Since the razor file is using a foreach as opposed to the ng-repeat I don't see how I can use $index.

```
 @foreach (var deal in @Model.Deals.Take(Model.NumberOfFaresToDisplay ?? 6))
                {
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know much of razor, but can't you do `@var index = 0;` before the `@foreach` ? If so, you could use `@index++;` inside the `@foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is here:
[Getting index value on razor foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10326406/getting-index-value-on-razor-foreach)

```
@{int i = 0;}
 @foreach(var myItem in Model.Members)
 {
     <span>@i</span>
     i++;
 }
```